# Debug an 'eclipse RCP application" remotely using Eclipse

Tags: java, debugging, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, remote-debugging

I am working on eclipse RCP wherein there are numerous intgrated plugins. The project is built into a .exe installer. My plugin classes are under the usual /plugins folder of this installed eclipse application.
Is there a way by which I can run the installed eclipse application in debugging mode by attaching the original source ?

Please let me know if further clarifications required.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The main problem will be that you need to pass some parameters to the JVM, such as:

`java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8001,server=y  suspend=y -jar stockTradingGUI.jar`. Read more [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.se/2011/02/how-to-setup-remote-debugging-in.html)

So unless the executable is configured to handle parameters and pass them on, you will have problems. 
But if the application is Eclipse RCP based, you could start it through Java by doing something like this;

`java -jar plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.x.y.jar -application my.product.id -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8001,server=y  suspend=y`

You may need to experiment with the exact parameters a bit and look in the [help](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/launcher.html) if there are more you need to set. But it is my understanding that in an RCP application the exe-file is more or less just a fancy shortcut to start up the launcher.

Comment: Hi Fredrik- Thanks for sharing the info... I had a query. What is -application my.product.id  and -jar myJar.jar ?

Comment: For "-application" you must enter the id you have given the product. This can be found in the manifest file of the product plugin you have created. The second "-jar" was a copy/paste error on my part, the answer has now been edited.

Comment: @Fredrik- I tried the above but i am having issues ..maybe because the RCP application that i have to run is composed of a number of plugins. Will this way work if we have an application with numerous plugins?

Comment: @tm.sauron Yes it will work. But it's a fairly complex operation. I suggest you start small and make sure you are doing things correctly. Test by writing a "hello world" and try to remote debug it.